# running a script in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a very simple script in my crontab that I want to run every day. It is located in `/home`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root        root     40 Apr 15 08:01 kill_slony_stop_sql.sh
```

It has execute permission and here is the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
slon_kill;rcpostgresql stop
```

and here is the cron line for it to run daily:

```
56 12 * * * /home/kill_slony_stop_sql.sh
```

But it is not working for some reason. When I type `/home/kill_slony_stop_sql.sh` in the command line, it works good but it is not working in the crontab.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please review the [`crontab` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for troubleshooting tips.  This is a very common FAQ and usually not programming-related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a daily cron job, I used the @daily but this will run at 00:00 every day.

```
@daily /usr/local/bin/msa70_check.sh
```

was the cron tab line i added, below is the script i run.

```
#!/bin/bash
# msa70 disk check
/sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md0 /dev/md1|
/bin/mailx -s"Disk check on server123 please check" person@domain.com
```

I also had to edit my script and add /sbin/ and /bin in front of mdadm and mailx for the cron job to run

Comment: I am not sure it is a astersik problem since I have many other tasks that works with that notation, and I need it to run at that specific time because the trafic on the server will be low

Comment: thanks paul It worked after adding before each command the complete path, I actually located the slon and rcpostgresql commands and fixed the script to the following:

#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/slon_kill; /usr/sbin/rcpostgresql stop

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a `PATH` issue. Have a look at [Why is my crontab not running](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) and be sure to set a PATH so that it can call your slon_kill command.

Also, add some debug to your cron

```
56 12 * * * /home/kill_slony_stop_sql.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log
```

And also look at the logs; cron logs its actions via syslog, which (depending on your setup) often go to `/var/log/cron` or `/var/log/syslog`.